# How can I update or insert a row with NULL fields using query builder?

Tags: database

In Drupal 7, I'm being sent an array of values from a user submission that are being mapped directly to a database table.

Some of those are blank and I'd like to set those fields to SQL-style `NULL` in the database.

To do this, my values array has the empty or blank fields set to PHP's `NULL`:

```
array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => NULL)
```

And I'm using `db_update()` like this:

```
$result = db_update('table_name')                                                           
  ->fields($record)                                                                                   
  ->condition('cmid', $form_state['values']['cmid'])                                                  
  ->execute();
```

However, `db_update()` doesn't appear to like `NULL` values in the `$record` array. I'm not seeing any sort of errors, unfortunately, except that no updates are being made to the database and that `$result` is returning a falsy value.

How should I be using `db_insert()` or `db_update()` if some my values may be blank at times, and I'd like these to equate to setting those respective database fields to `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db_update()` does allow `NULL` to be used for field values. To confirm this, check out the core table, `block_custom`, which allows both `block_custom.body` and `block_custom.format` to be `NULL`.

First, insert some dummy data either through the block administration screen or via SQL:

```
INSERT INTO block_custom (body, info, format)
  VALUES ('Lorem Ipsum', 'Test block', 'plain_text');
```

Now run the following code:

```
db_update('block_custom')
  ->fields(array('body' => NULL))
  ->condition('info', 'Test block')
  ->execute();
```

If you look at the table after executing, `block_custom.body` will be set to `NULL`.

`db_insert()` works too:

```
$fields = array(
  'body' => NULL,
  'info' => 'Test block 2',
  'format' => 'plain_text',
);

$result = db_insert('block_custom')
  ->fields($fields)
  ->execute();
```

So there's something else wrong with your statement. Two things to check:

- Ensure `$record` really has `NULL` values in the `db_update()` query. `var_dump()` the array just before the `db_update()` and ensure nothing's modified the values.
- Check the condition statement. If set to a condition that doesn't match any of the rows in the table, the update won't occur and `$result` will contain a falsy value. Since it's perfectly value to have an `UPDATE` query that matches no rows, it won't throw an exception or return an error.

Answer (score 1):

The following thread seems to contain your answer:

[Null Values Not Inserted Into Database Using db_insert](http://drupal.org/node/1113500).

Specifically:

> As your error message states, the column does not allow null values. Since the database won't accept null values for that table.column, you will need to send it something other than null, i.e. an empty string '' or whatever you decide the appropriate non-null value is.
>
> There is no getting around a column level constraint on a database unless you modify the table.column so that it allows nulls. That is not recommended, since such constraints are defined for a reason

This answer also seems to give some more insight into the Field API: [PDOException: Incorrect decimal value for a field which is legitimately null](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/pdoexception-incorrect-decimal-value-for-a-field-which-is-legitimately-null)

Comment: Except in my case, NULL is allowed in the column.

Comment: Have a look at this answer as well: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/pdoexception-incorrect-decimal-value-for-a-field-which-is-legitimately-null - it's not exactly your question, but I think the answer or some clues might be in there.